# Electronjs Unable to open X display

Tags: javascript, electron

I get the following error when trying to start an Electronjs app

```
[299:1006/231946.753542:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1400)] Unable to open X display.

The futex facility returned an unexpected error code./mnt/c/dev/XXXXX/electron-vue/node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGABRT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that I was trying to start the Electronjs app using WSL on windows. Since WSL doesn't support a GUI (headless) it can't launch the ElectronJS app.

Run the Electronjs app from Windows instead of WSL